# Previous Webpage PHP function

Tags: php

I'm not sure if this is possible or not. I want to get the webpage url the user came from to reach a page on my website. Is there a function that can find that info out for me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` will give you that value, but it could be faked or disabled by the client.

Comment: Question. Is there a function that can be trusted?

Comment: @jason328 You can store something in the users session

Comment: @jason328 for the most part, you can trust the value that it returns. However, if a user really wanted to, they could change the value to anything they wanted. What it returns is the value stored in the `Referer` field of the `HTTP` header that the user sends to your website when requesting a web page.